# Assign a template function to boost::function

Tags: c++, boost, function-templates

I want to do something like this toy program:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void func1(T& g) {
    std::cout << 1;
}

template <typename T>
void func2(T& g) {
    std::cout << 2;
}

int main() {
    boost::function<void(int)> f;
    int k;
    std::cin >> k;
    if (k == 1)
        f = func1 < int > ;
    else
        f = func2 < int > ;
}
```

But this code doesn't work and it says the "operator=" isn't clear. Is there any methods I can do something like this?

Comment: Please post the exact error. I [can't reproduce it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f6ca5d62f89e4b6) on Coliru.

Comment: Sorry, it's  error C2593 'operator =' is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
boost::function<void(int)> f;
```

to this:

```
boost::function<void(int&)> f;
```

So that it matches your functions.

---

In other news, the C++11 standard adopted essentially `boost::function` as `std::function`, with header `<functional>`.

Comment: Oh sorry, in the original code it has '&' behind the class name... And change it as your answer still get the same error in VS 2013...

Comment: @XiaofanNiu: The fix in this answer answers your posted question. Please do not present made-up code in a question: copy and paste code. Apparently you now have a second question. Post that separately. Be sure to include a **complete but minimal example** that readers can try out, and be sure to copy and paste that code.